# How to create dropdown with multiple columns?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in CSS, however it will have about 21 sub-items. I would therefore like to display them in 3 columns of 7, however I cannot figure out how to do so.

I have created a jsFiddle with a simple example, how can I ammend the CSS so that sub 6-10 are displayed to the right of sub 1-5, as opposed to below?

It should look like the image below, which was created in MS Paint.

**EDIT :**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07spd07b/)

[image]

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Group</a>
      <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Five</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Eight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Ten</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could we have the link to the jsFiddle?

Comment: Please share your code what you have done so fay... Try creating a demo of your code using jsfiddle.net and share! That will be more helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link, I've just edited my post to include

Comment: If the menu items are short, you can float, use a clearing on the holder, if they are unknown, you can use css columns.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/07spd07b/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use `float: left` to make them stack

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/07spd07b/2/

```
#top-level-group{
    width: 200px;
}
#top-level-group ul{
    float: left;
}
```

In the sample I changed the original position from `-9999px` left so you can see it right when you open the jsfiddle. Set the width depending on the content you want to put inside. If you want more columns give it more width.

**UPDATE**

Here is the working sample with 3 columns and the clearfix included:

http://jsfiddle.net/07spd07b/10/

I added class clearfix:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; }
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both; }
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1; }
```

Which clears floating elements and set the `width: 250px;` to fit the 3 columns. Hope it helps.

Comment: width should be increased to allow for the 3rd column but this works great!

Comment: Oh sure sorry, forgot he wanted 3 columns

Comment: Perfect thanks, I had tried `float:left`, but never thought of setting the width of the parent! Still alot to learn

Comment: @user184994 dont't forget to mark the answer as correct. I will update my answer including the clearing of the floating elements, check it out in a minute, I almost forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite easily by using `display:inline-block;`:

```
nav ul li ul{
display:inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Then you just need to give the div a width:

```
nav ul li div {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
width:300px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/07spd07b/8/)
To add more columns, just make more `<ul>`'s and set the width wider.

Answer (score 0):

please now  check this link .. I've added two class in `<ul>` tags and styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/07spd07b/