# How to create a dropdown list with multiple adjacent 'columns'

Tags: html, css, dropdown, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write code for a shopping-website style dropdown that when one hovers over a target element on the navigation bar, it functions like the one depicted at this [site](https://www.hss.com/hire).

I've spent two days on this, looking at so many pages, including previous postings on Stackoverflow, and tried what seems like an endless number of approaches, but I've simply not been able to crack this.

I should stress that I can already write the code for a dropdown that generates a single column of list of links when one hovers over the target element (that's easy); I'm really talking about aligned adjacent multiple columns.

A solution for a problem like this was posted here on Stackoverflow several years ago, but the person suggested the float method. I did actually try this, but the results were (very) unsatisfactory for my project.

If you can help me with this, to (instantly) see what my code looks like when rendered and painted, I've posted the necessary bits of code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/charlesumesi/pen/xxWbrdJ), but the code is also posted below:

HTML:

```css
.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  background-color: #429CD9;
}

#hire-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #429CD9;
}

.the-drop {
  display: none;
}

#hire-dropdown:hover>.the-drop {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "drop-1-list drop-2-list";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.drop-1-list,
.drop-2-list {
  display: none;
}

.drop-1-list {
  grid-area: "drop-1-list";
}

.drop-2-list {
  grid-area: "drop-2-list";
}

.the-drop:hover>.drop-1-list,
.the-drop:hover>.drop-2-list {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>Nothing</li>
    <li class="to-hire">
      <div id="hire-dropdown">To Hire
        <div class=".the-drop">
          <ul class="drop-1-list">
            <li><a href="#">Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Breaking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Compaction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cooling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drilling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lifting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sanding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sawing</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="drop-2-list">
            <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you also want to see the float method solution I referred to earlier, you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651215/how-to-create-dropdown-with-multiple-columns) (but I do not believe this is the right solution for my project).

Your (constructive) help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for a megamenu? What was unsatisfactory about the solution using `float`?

Comment: Hi David, yeah the problem was that although the second list did float to the right, it did so at the bottom of the container and would not align adjacent right to the first list despite extending the width of the container; I therefore went for a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure how you want to handle all the narrow displays etc. but

- `<div class=".the-drop">` remove the period on the class in the markup
- Remove some CSS - most of the time with CSS when you have issues remove some to get back to "basic" this work your way to your goal.  I did that and adjusted some CSS selectors.  No need for the `absolute` I think.
- with the flex and then display of the blocks it jumps around a bit but I will leave that to you as to how you address that.

```css
.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  background-color: #429CD9;
}

#hire-dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #429CD9;
}

.the-drop,
.drop-1-list,
.drop-2-list {
  display: none;
}

#hire-dropdown:hover * {
  display: grid;
}

#hire-dropdown .the-drop {
  grid-template-areas: "drop-1-list drop-2-list";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.drop-1-list,
.drop-2-list {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
}

.drop-1-list {
  grid-area: "drop-1-list";
}

.drop-2-list {
  grid-area: "drop-2-list";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>Nothing</li>
    <li class="to-hire">
      <div id="hire-dropdown">To Hire
        <div class="the-drop">
          <ul class="drop-1-list">
            <li><a href="#">Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Breaking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Compaction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cooling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drilling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lifting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sanding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sawing</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="drop-2-list">
            <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, your solution did indeed work. The only thing to add is that the absolute positioning for #hire-dropdown is actually needed as it prevents the navigation bar from elongating when the dropdown appears, as is the case with your solution. Nonetheless, your solution was very helpful and so I am ticking it! I do have a follow-on question from my first one, but it is a different question and so I will set it up in a new post (if it hasn't already been answered).

Answer (score 0):

Jquery to handle the events

```
$(function() {
  $(".to-hire").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.the-drop').show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.the-drop').hide();
  });
});
```

You have a `.` in the class name here `<div class=".the-drop">`, remove it.

Remove these lines of code from your CSS

```
.drop-1-list,
.drop-2-list {
    display: none;
}
```

Now what should happen is, when your mouse goes onto the dropdown menu link, your dropdown should show, when it leaves it will hide

Comment: No need for the script, I believe this can all be CSS

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yep. I believe a simple `:hover` should fix the issue on the `.to-hire` class. Just wanted to provide an alternate approach

Comment: Yep, nothing "wrong" here but just added a comment for others just in case

Comment: A very interesting suggestion @JamesS. I actually did try using the JQuery hover function before posting the question, but I couldn't quite get it to work. I had not however, tried the separate functions of mouseenter and mouseleave (I was aware of them), so this is definitely one to have in 'my locker'; thanks.